# To display the time in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, time

I created a simple game in C in Xcode, but time does not elapse. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
int main(void)
{
   long startTime = 0;
   long totalTime = 0;
   long prevtime = 0;
   int num;
   init();
   cursor = arrayFish;
   startTime = clock();
   while (1)
   {
     printFishes();
     printf("\n Which fishing port would you like to water? ");
     scanf("%d", &num);
     printf("\n");
     if (num > 6 || num < 1)
     {
       printf("Please re-enter.\n");
       continue;
     }
   }
   totalTime = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Total Elapsed Time: %ld\n", totalTime);
}
```

It works except for the time mark. So I just wrote the code needed. Thank you.

Comment: Try `time` instead of `clock`.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know how long has it been. only seconds. If the time go by three second, I want to mark 3s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know Time Stamp Counter register your clock function is reading. If it is a 32 bit register it will reset very frequently. 
For example if your CPU has 2GHz clock then `1 sec = 2 * 1e9 cycles` and 32 bit unsigned register can count from `0 to 2^32 - 1` cycles. Which is equal to `(2^32)/(2*1e9) = 2.14748365 seconds`. 
In this case your output will always be limited to `2.14 seconds`